# Смена URL страницы на самописном сайте

Tags: php, html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой на которую не смог найти ответ.
Есть самописный сайт на html + css.
При заплитии сайта на хостинг, по умолчанию, открывается файл `index.html`.

Как можно сменить URL страницы что бы было не `www.site.com/index.html`, а `www.site.com/home` ?

Comment: Вопрос поставлен неверно. Правильный вопрос `Как сделать так, чтобы запрос www.site.com/home был направлен на файл index.html в папке сайта?`. Запросы направляются на файл через веб сервер, веб сервер же и решает - выполнить файл(PHP) или вернуть его контент(JPG например). То есть URL адрес и файлы на сервере в принципе никак не связаны в 99% сайтов. Учите теорию HTTP и маршрутизации через сервер - без этого не стать высокооплачиваемым спецом...

Answer (score -1):

. htacess файл создаете и там прописываете команду RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^reg/?$ /game/reg.php [L,QSA]
Флаг QSA означает добавление существующей строки запроса после перезаписывания URI. Пример:

URL = http://example.com/foo/bar?q=blah

Правило:

RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /index.php?b=$1 Результат = /index.php?b=bar

Обратите внимание на то, что q=blah отсутствует. Поскольку существующая строка запроса отбрасывается в пользу той, которая указана в целевом правиле, (b = $1). Теперь, если вы включили флаг QSA:

RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /index.php?b=$1 [QSA] Результат становится = /index.php?b=bar&q=blah

Флаг L просто означает прекратить применение каких-либо правил. Учитывая тот же URL-адрес, http://example.com/foo/bar?q=blah и заданные правила:

RewriteRule ^foo -

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar.php RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.php?z=$1 Первое правило применяется, и URI передается без изменений (через целевой объект -). Затем механизм перезаписи обрабатывает следующее правило, и URI переписывается на /bar.php?z=foo/bar. Что происходит, когда вы добавляете L в конец:

RewriteRule ^foo - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar.php RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.php?z=$1 URL http://example.com/foo/bar передается без изменений из первого правила, а затем останавливается из-за флага L. Если URL-адрес http://example.com/something/else, то первое правило не соответствует, а второе правило применяется, переписывая URI на: /bar.php?z=something/else

Обратите внимание, что, поскольку механизм перезаписи проходит все правила до тех пор, пока URI не перестанет меняться, флаг L не будет препятствовать циклу, только любые дополнительные правила будут применяться в текущей итерации